# Fullcalendar appears only after page reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, fullcalendar

When a user visits a user profile they should see a calendar.

On first load the calendar does not appear. It will only appear after reloading the page.

How can I fix this?

Coffee script:

```
$(document).ready ->
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar(
        events: "#{window.Configuration.UserId}/events.json"
    )
```

Comment: Anything wrong in the logs? It might be that the `window.Configuration.UserId` is null. In my experience, it is better to put the `UserId` in a `data` attribute in the `HTML` and fetch it using `jQuery` in you coffeescript.

Comment: no, check it, problem not here. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using turbolinks? If yes, try disabling them and see what happens. If the problem goes away you can either continue without TL, or install the `jquery-turbolinks` gem.